# Solve for Swipe feature (facebook) Xcode

Tags: ios, facebook, swipe

I have found out for swipe feature and I can use it in my app. https://github.com/YoonBongKim/SwipeMenuDemo
But the problem is that when i use, I need to change my root view controller like this in Appdelegate.m .

```
YBSwipeViewController *swipeRootViewCntrlr = [[YBSwipeViewController alloc]     initWithMainViewController:mainNavigationCntrlr menuViewController:menuNavigationCntrlr];
self.window.rootViewController = swipeRootViewCntrlr;
```

As a result, my original viewcontroller is not working. My original viewcontroller is linked with other controller. I can still swipe. But when viewcontroller need to call from other class, the application crush. I would like to know how to do.

Comment: What crash report are you getting ?

Comment: I got *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'OBHistory''

Comment: it only occur when i change root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going for something that does the exact same thing but with 317 stars on GitHub
https://github.com/meiwin/MWFSlideNavigationViewController

I'm not saying the class you provided doesn't work but it's a lot easier if there's a big community behind the project.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But I need to drag the view and animate. i need to use UIPanGestureRecognizer.